# Carbon wrong datetime after loop

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, time, php-carbon

i tried to add four times 30. Minutes in a controller (laravel) but the result is wrong.

Here my code:

```
$start = Carbon::parse($request['start']);
$end = Carbon::parse($request['end']);



 $tmp = $start->copy();
 for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++){
    $tmp = $tmp->addMinutes("30"); // same result with addMinutes(30)
 }
```

Start: 2017-06-23 09:30:00 
End: 2017-06-23 11:00:00 
Expected result for $tmp : 2017-06-23 11:30:00 
Received result for $tmp : 2017-06-23 15:00:00

I have no explanation for this result.
What did i wrong?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure, but try adding it as a number: `$tmp = $tmp->addMinutes(30);`.

Comment: I already tried this but same result

Comment: Are you sure the start date has been parsed correctly to start with?

Comment: So the addminutes is working but it's the end time that's wrong?

Comment: Please provide the input for `$request`

Comment: Try echoing/logging `$tmp` in each loop to see what it contains.

Comment: After testing this myself, I could not reproduce your problem.  The accepted answer also doesn't appear to do anything that would change the outcome of $tmp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$start = Carbon::parse($request['start']);
$end = Carbon::parse($request['end']);

$tmp = Carbon::parse($start);
for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++){
    $tmp->addMinutes(30);
}

dd([
    'start' => $start,
    'tmp' => $tmp
]);
```

This way you will get dumped an array that has first value your original parsed value (you can see that this is what you expect it to be) and second value will be `start + 2 hours` so you can debug this as well.

Comment: Thanks! I thought the $start->copy() is already a Carbon Object

Comment: @Eddy05, it is... so Carbon::parse shouldn't change anything.

Comment: @Eddy05 Yeah it would make sense. I went throught exactly same a few weeks ago, this was the solution I used. I wouldn't be surprised if there was a nicer way though.